# Javascript function creating tabs not working properly during onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried to follow this example to create tabs for my website: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Everything works well, but opening the default tag isn't working as it should. The tab opens, but it does not set the header color correctly.

Here's my HTML for the tablinks:

```
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
<ul class="tab">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Protons')" id="onDefault">Ions</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Electrons')">Electrons, X-rays and CME's</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here's the script for the tabs

```
function openTab(evt, tab) {

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i=0;i<tabcontent.length;i++){
    tabcontent[i].style.display="none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

  for (var i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(tab).style.display="block";
  evt.currentTarget.tab += " active";
}
```

I'm currently clicking the event using

```
<script>document.getElementById('onDefault').click();</script>
```

This does not produce any error messages, but when I use Jquery, i.e.:

```
<script>$('#onDefault').click()</script>
```

I get an error saying:

```
scripts.js:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tab' of undefined
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Try using your browser's JavaScript debugger (in Break+Step-Through mode). You'll find the problem easily.

Comment: _“I'm currently clicking the event using `<script>document.getElementById('onDefault')</script>`”_ – there is nothing in that code that would trigger a click, all it does is get the reference to an element via its id.

Comment: I think the error lies `evt.currentTarget.tab += " active";` here. **Side tip**: use [jQueryUI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I didn't copy-paste it properly. Edited the code snippet.

Comment: @P4nd4b0b3r1n0, don't go for copy paste untill you understand what the code is for.. what each line is doing.. first read it properly then paste.. hope this will work for you in future as well

Comment: Please add the markup for the element with the id `Protons` which you reference here: `document.getElementById(tab).style.display="block";`

Comment: Note your use of `evt.currentTarget.tab` generates this error, what exactly is this `tab` you hope to reference?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of jquery is kinda nonexistent and the example clearly does not use jquery - therefore I would call it misstagged.

```
<script>document.getElementById('onDefault').click();</script>
```

The first one does not throw an error because the currentTarget is a property of the normal event. A nonexisting property .tab gets set on it, yet doing nothing.

```
<script>$('#onDefault').click()</script>
```

The second one (jquery) has a built in property currentTarget which is undefined in this case - leading to the written error.

> Any ideas what's going on?

You did not define tab or in case jquery its owner.. where exactly?

> evt.**currentTarget.tab** += " active";

Thus you get the justified browser error:

```
scripts.js:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tab' of undefined
```

In the linked example at this place the className is extended:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

> evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

```
// Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

Depending on what you try to achieve this might or might not be correct.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget
https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/